# Displaying an Integer as an output of Xs

Tags: java, string, integer

So, I'm pretty new to the Java language and am having problem with a homework assignment. I need to take a console input from the user and display the number as a line of Xs. (i.e. "Cars sold by Pam > 3" will display "Pam XXX" 
Here is what I have so far. Once I get to the if statement, I am at a loss of what to do next. I have tried to look up many different resolutions, but can't find anything that describes exactly what I need to do. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarGraph2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    int pam;
    int leo;
    int kim;
    int bob;

    Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of cars sold by Pam > ");        
        pam = p.nextInt();

    Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of cars sold by Leo > ");        
        leo = l.nextInt();

    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of cars sold by Kim > ");        
        kim = k.nextInt();

    Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of cars sold by Bob > ");        
        bob = b.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nCar Sales for the Month:");

    if(pam > 0)
        {   
            String pamSales = valueOf(int pam);

            pamSales.setLength

            System.out.print( "\nPam  " + pamSales);
        }
    else
        {
            System.out.print("\nPam  ");
        }

    }


}
```

Edit: I got it finally...I think my brain was just fried? Thanks guys.

Comment: please dont create a new scanner each time it makes me cringe just use one

Comment: @Rush2sk8 ...you can do that? (bear with me here, just starting)

Comment: @klane361 Yes, you just create one `Scanner` and use the `nextInt()` method every time you want to get a value. `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);` ... `pam = s.nextInt()` ... `leo = s.nextInt()` ... `kim = s.nextInt()` ...

Comment: @mdl Good deal. Helped clean up things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run a loop like :-

```
System.out.print("PAM");    
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)    // here n is the required number of repetition
System.out.print("X");
```

Comment: Got it, finally. And that's exactly what I had to do. Thanks for the response!